# Riemann sum $\displaystyle F(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\text{sinc}(\pi(x+k)) \ln\left(\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I need help calculating this limit as a function of $x$:
$$F(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin(\pi(x+k))}{\pi(x+k)}\ln\left(\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\right)$$
I wanted to use the Riemann sum method in such a way $F(x)$ as to write as an integral, but the logarithm appears and I can't find a way to write it differently.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me a suggestion

> I believe that the solution is:
>
> $$F(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\left(xt\right)\cot\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}t+\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{2\pi x}-\frac{1}{2}$$
>
> (or something like that) but I don't know how to prove it.
>
> - There could be a correlation since $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln(\sin(x))=\cot(x)$

I think it might also be useful to consider the Riemann–Stieltjes integral:

$${\displaystyle \int _{a}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm {d} g(x)=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int _{a}^{b}g(x)\,\mathrm {d} f(x)}$$

Comment: One thing that might help is: when trying to recognize a limit of a summation as a definite integral on an interval $[a,b]$, the partition of the interval doesn't have to be uniform. In other words, $x_k^*$ does not necessarily need to equal $a + \frac{k}{n}$ for all $k$. A classic example I know of is computing $\int_1^a \sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x$ using the partition $x_k^* = a^{\frac{k}{n}}$. What matters is that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{k+1}^* - x_{k}^* = 0$. So the $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ term in your problem might be resolvable using a "non-standard" $\Delta x$.

Comment: @T.Ochse just to be sure so I can make a comparison with a different example than the others, in this case the series would be: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{a^{\frac{k}{n}}}}{a^{\frac{k+1}{n}}-a^{\frac{k}{n}}}$? 
(I think not because I did some tests and I get a much larger number)

Comment: The $\Delta x$ is being multiplied in the sum, rather than divided. So in the example I gave, using left endpoints of the partition, the nth Riemann sum should be $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k/2n}(a^{(k+1)/n}-a^{k/n})$. Notice we rewrote $\sqrt{a^{k/n}}$ using exponent rules.

Comment: @T.Ochse Thanks, it works now.

Comment: Just as an idea, it may be simpler to first calculate the Fourier-transform $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\rm d}x \, F(x) \, e^{-i\omega x} = \frac{1}{\log n} \, {\rm rect}\left(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\right) \sum_{k=1}^n \log\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right) \, e^{i\omega k} \, .$$

Comment: @Diger I tried, but the problem is that the logarithm remains and the "$k/n$" does not appear in the exponential :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can write
$$\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi \cos(t(x+k)) \, {\rm d}t=\frac{\sin(\pi(x+k))}{\pi(x+k)} \, $$
and so
$$F(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\pi \log n} \int_0^\pi {\rm d}t \, \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(t(x+k)) \log\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right) \\
=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\pi \log n} \int_0^\pi {\rm d}t \, \Re\left( e^{itx} \sum_{k=1}^n e^{itk} \log\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right) \right) \, .$$
Consider then the function
$$f_n(t)=\frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{itk} \log\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right) \stackrel{{\rm sbp}}{=} -\frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{e^{itk}-1}{1-e^{-it}} \, \log \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi (k+1)}{2n}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)} \\
=\frac{1}{(1-e^{-it})\log n} \left\{ \log \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} e^{itk} \, \left[\log\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right) + \log\left(1+\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)}\right) \right] \right\} \, .$$
In the limit $n\to\infty$, the first term becomes just
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-it}} \, .$$
The second term contains a factor $\log\cos(\pi/2n)=O(1/n^2)$ while the geometric series converges in the limit $n\to\infty$. Hence, the second term vanishes in the limit.

The third term is a bit more complicated, but can be dealt with in a similar way. For large enough $n$, split the sum as follows
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} = \sum_{1\leq k\leq\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}} + \sum_{\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}} < k \leq n-1}$$
and so
$$\left| \sum_{\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}} < k \leq n-1} e^{itk} \log\left(1+\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)}\right) \right|
\leq \sum_{\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}} < k \leq n-1} \log\left(1+\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)}\right) \\
\leq \sum_{\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}} < k \leq n-1} \frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)}
< \sum_{\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}} < k \leq n-1} \frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\log n}}\right)} \\
< \frac{n \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\log n}}\right)} = O(\sqrt{\log n})=o(\log n) \, .$$

Likewise,
$$\sum_{1 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}} e^{itk} \log\left(1+\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)}\right)
\simeq \sum_{1 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}} e^{itk} \log\left(1+\frac1k\right) \\
=\sum_{1 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}} e^{itk} \left[\log\left(1+\frac1k\right) - \frac1k \right] + \sum_{1 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{\log n}}} \frac{e^{itk}}{k} \, .$$
The first term converges absolutely in the limit $n\to\infty$, while the second term converges to $-\log(1-e^{it})$. As a result
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t)=f(t)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-it}} \, .$$

Given this, it is not too complicated to calculate
$$\frac1\pi \Re\left( e^{itx} f(t) \right) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[ \cos(tx) + \sin(tx) \cot(t/2) \right] \, ,$$
which after integration gives your anticipated result.

Comment: Can you check if everything is correct? Because I know for a fact that it doesn't converge to $0$. I'll also leave you the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4mmg51psxl?lang=it

Comment: Where? So I'll correct it in case. (If you say for the negative part I know it's different, in fact I believe that the "possible solution" is missing a piece)

Comment: You said there is an error in the input but I didn't understand where. The possibile solution should be something like $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\left(xt\right)\cot\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)dt+\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{2\pi x}-\frac{1}{2}$